# Apache .htaccess gets overwritten all the time

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, server, system-administration

I use the .htaccess file from apache2 in /var/www/html/, after a while the file gets overwritten with what seem to be a default config file and I don't know why..
I don't use Wordpress or any CMS.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was cause by "grunt build" that would automatically create an .htaccess file for me...